# Mysql 8.0 JSON индексация

Tags: mysql, json

Читал на хабре статью про mysql JSON, цитирую:

"С момента введения поддержки типа данных JSON в MySQL 5.7.8 не хватает одной вещи: способности индексировать значения JSON."

Интересует вопрос, в 8.0 мускуле появилась ли способность индексировать значение?

И есть потенциальная система Х, в которой надо понять, что использовать - Пострге или Мускуль, но там точно будет большое кол-во данных JSON.

Comment: [Indexing a Generated Column to Provide a JSON Column Index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-secondary-indexes.html#json-column-indirect-index)

Comment: Если много JSON, то используйте MongoDB (https://www.mongodb.com/)